# Unable to manually send Lotus Notes email in excel

Tags: php, excel, email

I'm trying to use Macro to send Lotus Notes email to customers, I'm able to send it automatically, but in case there's anything I would like to add it before sending, so I want to set it as a manual mode, so that I can view the email first, and probably make some change before sending, so my question is how should I amend it? I have some ways but they are not working.

I will then post my entire code with automatic sending function:

```
Sub Send_Unformatted_Rangedata(i As Integer)
Dim noSession As Object, noDatabase As Object, noDocument As Object
Dim vaRecipient As Variant
Dim rnBody As Range
Dim Data As DataObject
Dim rngGen As Range
Dim rngApp As Range
Dim rngspc As Range

Dim stSubject As String
stSubject = "E-Mail For Approval for " + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value) + "  for the Project  " + Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
'Const stMsg As String = "Data as part of the e-mail's body."
'Const stPrompt As String = "Please select the range:"

'This is one technique to send an e-mail to many recipients but for larger
'number of recipients it's more convenient to read the recipient-list from
'a range in the workbook.
vaRecipient = VBA.Array(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "U").Value, Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "V").Value)

 On Error Resume Next
'Set rnBody = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=stPrompt, _
     Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
 'The user canceled the operation.
'If rnBody Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 Set rngGen = Nothing
 Set rngApp = Nothing
 Set rngspc = Nothing

 Set rngGen = Sheets("General Overview").Range("A1:C30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Set rngApp = Sheets("Application").Range("A1:E13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

 Set rngspc = Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "Q").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Set rngspc = Union(rngspc, Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "R").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

  On Error GoTo 0

  If rngGen Is Nothing And rngApp Is Nothing And rngspc Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
      Exit Sub
  End If

'Instantiate Lotus Notes COM's objects.
Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("", "")

'Make sure Lotus Notes is open and available.
If noDatabase.IsOpen = False Then noDatabase.OPENMAIL

'Create the document for the e-mail.
Set noDocument = noDatabase.CreateDocument

'Copy the selected range into memory.
rngGen.Copy
rngApp.Copy
rngspc.Copy

'Retrieve the data from then copied range.
Set Data = New DataObject
Data.GetFromClipboard

'Add data to the mainproperties of the e-mail's document.
With noDocument
    .Form = "Memo"
    .SendTo = vaRecipient
    .Subject = stSubject
    'Retrieve the data from the clipboard.
    .Body = Data.GetText & " " & stMsg
    .SaveMessageOnSend = True
End With

'Send the e-mail.
With noDocument
    .PostedDate = Now()
    .send 0, vaRecipient
End With

'Release objects from memory.
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing

'Activate Excel for the user.
'Change Microsoft Excel to Excel
AppActivate "Excel"

'Empty the clipboard.
Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed.", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub Send_Formatted_Range_Data(i As Integer)
Dim oWorkSpace As Object, oUIDoc As Object
Dim rnBody As Range
Dim lnRetVal As Long
Dim stTo As String
Dim stCC As String
Dim stSubject As String
Const stMsg As String = "An e-mail has been succesfully created and saved."

Dim rngGen As Range
Dim rngApp As Range
Dim rngspc As Range

stTo = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "U").Value
stCC = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "V").Value
stSubject = "E-Mail For Approval for " + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value) + "  for the Project  " + Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")

'Check if Lotus Notes is open or not.
lnRetVal = FindWindow("NOTES", vbNullString)

If lnRetVal = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please make sure that Lotus Notes is open!", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set rngGen = Sheets("General Overview").Range("A1:C30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Set rngApp = Sheets("Application").Range("A1:E13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

 Set rngspc = Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "Q").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Set rngspc = Union(rngspc, Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "R").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
 On Error GoTo 0

If rngGen Is Nothing And rngApp Is Nothing And rngspc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

rngGen.Copy
rngApp.Copy
rngspc.Copy

'Instantiate the Lotus Notes COM's objects.
Set oWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

On Error Resume Next

Set oUIDoc = oWorkSpace.ComposeDocument("", "mail\xldennis.nsf", "Memo")
On Error GoTo 0

Set oUIDoc = oWorkSpace.CurrentDocument

'Using LotusScript to create the e-mail.
Call oUIDoc.FieldSetText("EnterSendTo", stTo)
Call oUIDoc.FieldSetText("EnterCopyTo", stCC)
Call oUIDoc.FieldSetText("Subject", stSubject)

'If You experience any issues with the above three lines then replace it with:
'Call oUIDoc.FieldAppendText("EnterSendTo", stTo)
'Call oUIDoc.FieldAppendText("EnterCopyTo", stCC)
'Call oUIDoc.FieldAppendText("Subject", stSubject)

'The can be used if You want to add a message into the created document.
Call oUIDoc.FieldAppendText("Body", vbNewLine & stBody)

'Here the selected range is pasted into the body of the outgoing e-mail.
Call oUIDoc.GoToField("Body")
Call oUIDoc.Paste

'Save the created document.
Call oUIDoc.Save(True, False, False)
'If the e-mail also should be sent then add the following line.
'Call oUIDoc.Send(True)

'Release objects from memory.
Set oWorkSpace = Nothing
Set oUIDoc = Nothing

With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

MsgBox stMsg, vbInformation

'Activate Lotus Notes.
 AppActivate ("Notes")
'Last edited Feb 11, 2015 by Peter Moncera

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code I have for my lotus notes to send or display is shown below, you'll need to amend it for your code. For me activecell.offset(0,11) has either 'Send' or 'Display' written in it.

```
'Send the document
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = "Send" Then
    MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True
    MailDoc.PostedDate = Now()
    Call MailDoc.Send(0, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value)
Else
    MailDoc.Save True, True, False
    Set uiMemo = ws.EditDocument(True, MailDoc)
End If
```

**EDIT**
The above code is for if you want the option to send/display based on a parameter in your spreadsheet. For your specific issue, you will need to change this code, (it might be worth removing this code and seeing if the email displays in lotus notes):

```
'Send the e-mail.
With noDocument
    .PostedDate = Now()
    .send 0, vaRecipient
End With
```

If after removing the above code, running it and it doesn't display in Lotus Notes, replace the above with the below code:

```
'Send the e-mail.
Dim uiMemo As Object
Dim ws As Object
Set ws = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
noDocument.Save True, True, False
Set uiMemo = ws.EditDocument(True, noDocument)
```

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: I have error message for `MailDoc.Save True, True, False`, may I know how I should amend it? Since I already feel a bit lost:(

Comment: hi and your activecell is based on which cell?

Comment: As I mentioned you will need to amend for your code i.e. You will want to change MailDoc to noDocument. ActiveCell for me is based on a cell in my spreadsheet, again you will need to change for the parameter which you use for Send/Display. I will edit my answer to assist you, and if in future you want the option to choose between sending and displaying you can edit your code to my initial answer.

Comment: Thanks, since I don't have a send/display cell and I'm not that familiar with excel functions, I'm quite lost to do that lol.